# Java: While Loop still running even when the condition is false

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, java.util.scanner, do-while

I'm fairly new at coding and in java in general but I'm hoping that I could get this figured out.  I have a do while loop and inside that, I have a while statement if the incorrect value is input in the Scanner. However, when I run the code it always runs the while command once regardless of whether it is incorrect or correct and then runs the code correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice {
public static void main (String [] args) {
int x = 0;
int i = 0;
int n = 0;
String S1 = "";

Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);


do
{
    System.out.println("Enter an integer between 1 and 15: ");
    x = user.nextInt();



        while ( x < 1 || x > 15);
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect integer. Must be between 1 and 15. Try again: ");
            x = user.nextInt();
        }

    n = 1;  


}
while (n != 1);


for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
{
    S1 = S1 + "X";
}

for (n = 1; n <= x; n++)
{
    System.out.println(S1);
}


    }


}
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: remove ; from the end of statements of while

Comment: @Satya From the first one only. The second one terminates a `do/while`, and there the semicolon is correct.

Comment: @EJP, you are right sir :) . Apologies for the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the extra `;` from your while loop

Like this:

```
  while ( x < 1 || x > 15){
            System.out.println("Incorrect integer. Must be between 1 and 15. Try again: ");
            x = user.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: From the first one only. The second one terminates a `do/while`, and there the semicolon is correct.

Comment: @turnipdabeets Thank you so much, I really appreciate it. I have a problem with adding semicolons after the end of each line. This worked perfectly!

Comment: @GavinWebb no problem, glad I could help!

Comment: Dont forget to use `user.close();` at the end of your application to close the keyboard input from the Scanner.

Comment: You used an icon labeled JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet.  Java is not JavaScript, HTML, or CSS, so you shouldn't use that icon.

Comment: @ajb I'm not sure how to get another snippet in StackOverflow... if you could enlighten me please :)

Comment: @GavinWebb please be sure to accept an answer if your question was answered :)

Answer (score 2):

while ( x < 1 || x > 15);
The Semi-Colon will terminate the logic and the control will pass to the next line always. Be careful while you code :D

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the extra semicolon in the while.
2. Also close the scanner object(user).

Check the updated code.

```
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int n = 0;
        String S1 = "";

        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer between 1 and 15: ");
            x = user.nextInt();

            while (x < 1 || x > 15)
            {
                System.out.println("Incorrect integer. Must be between 1 and 15. Try again: ");
                x = user.nextInt();
            }

            n = 1;

        } while (n != 1);

        for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
            S1 = S1 + "X";
        }

        for (n = 1; n <= x; n++) {
            System.out.println(S1);
        }

        user.close();

    }

}
```